# Android - ParseQuery<ParseObject> whereMatches returns empty list

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am writing a query to a parse.com server.

when I use whereContainedIn, I get back a List.

```
final ArrayList<String> searchList = new ArrayList<String>(1);
                    String searchRegexText = mSearchEdit.getText().toString();
                    searchList.add(searchRegexText);
                    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(TABLE_PRODUCTS);
                    query.whereContainedIn(KEYWORDS, searchList);
                    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) {
                            List<ParseObject> temp =  list;
                        }
                    });
```

When I use whereMatches I get back a empty list:

```
                    String searchRegexText = mSearchEdit.getText().toString();
                    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(TABLE_PRODUCTS);
                    query.whereMatches(KEYWORDS, searchRegexText);
                    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) {
                            List<ParseObject> temp =  list;
                        }
                    });
```

Why?

Answer (score 0):

According to the `Parse API` [here](https://parse.com/docs/android/api/?com/parse/ParseObject.html), For `ParseQuery`:

`whereContainedIn`:

```
public ParseQuery<T> whereContainedIn(String key,
                                      Collection<? extends Object> values)
```

Add a constraint to the query that requires a particular key's value to be contained in the provided list of values.

`whereMatches`:

```
public ParseQuery<T> whereMatches(String key,
                                  String regex)
```

Add a regular expression constraint for finding string values that match the provided regular expression. This may be slow for large datasets.

Obviously, the second one need the `Regex (Regular Expressions)`.

Comment: why mSearchEdit.getText().toString() is not a a regular expressions, meaning a string that has the same text like  mSearchEdit.getText().toString()?

Comment: Regex is different from regular String, something like this: (?<=\.) {2,}(?=[A-Z]). It uses for search. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression

Comment: so  in this case i need to use "(" +mSearchEdit.getText().toString() + ")"   ?

Comment: Not that simple. you can see the tutorial here: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLFA4F2FDD28D0C40E

Comment: That link dint help me. Its dosent deal with java reg syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are trying to query wrong. If you are just trying to query a specific key against a single value you can simple do this.

```
String searchRegexText = mSearchEdit.getText().toString();
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(TABLE_PRODUCTS);
query.whereEqualTo(KEYWORDS, searchRegexText);
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
    @Override
    public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) {
        List<ParseObject> temp =  list;
    }
});
```

I am assuming that 'KEYWORDS' is a string variable that defines the column name that you are searching in.

**EDIT:**

IF you are trying to find all objects that start with a specific string then you can use this instead:

```
String searchRegexText = mSearchEdit.getText().toString();
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(TABLE_PRODUCTS);
query.whereStartsWith(KEYWORDS, searchRegexText);
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
    @Override
    public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) {
        List<ParseObject> temp =  list;
    }
});
```

Comment: Actually, my final goal is to get all ParseObject that start with mSearchEdit.getText().toString(). so i need to use the whereMatches function.

Comment: Check the edit in my answer for a way to search the start of strings without having to use regular expressions

Comment: i tried your approach, but i get in the callback a ParseException e with the text:
"com.parse.ParseException: $regex only works on string fields"

Comment: What is the type of the column that is defined by KEYWORD?. The type needs to be of string to be able to work using this method

Comment: i dont know if it is a String, because i only work from the client side.
but if that was the problem, why whereContainedIn works for me? 
it aslo only takes only a String.